# Get duration between two dates (Moment JS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I have 2 dates. And need to find duration between them in this format `${y}year ${w}weeks ${d}d`

For this I created function. Here is code

```
 setTotalDuration(): void {
    const formattedFrom = moment(this.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    const formattedTo = moment(this.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    const duration = moment.duration(moment(formattedTo).diff(moment(formattedFrom)));
    const y = Math.floor(duration.asYears());
    const w = Math.floor(duration.asWeeks() - y * moment().weeksInYear());
    const d = Math.floor(duration.asDays() - w * 7);
    this.totalDuration = ` ${y}year ${w}weeks ${d}d`;
}
```

it works not correctly,  now if I pass for example startDate - 19/02/2020 and endDate - 19/02/2021, I get duration  - 1year -1weeks 373d. But I need to get 1year 0weeks 0d

Where is my problem?

Comment: I don't think you need duration, simply using the `diff` function with a granularity of `day` should be sufficient: `const dayDifference = moment(this.endDate).diff(moment(this.startDate), 'day');`

Comment: you are also performing redundant formats. You do not need them for duration calculations.

Comment: I've set up a small jsfiddle demonstrating how to use diff to achieve the desired result: https://jsfiddle.net/rmekv2s0/

Comment: its 366 days -> 51.8 weeks not 53 like in 2020

Comment: okay, if days for example will be 8, it will return me 1 week and 1 day? @nbokmans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you wanted.
You could get the difference in years and add that to the initial date; then get the difference in weeks and add that to the initial date again.

```
var moment = require("moment");

var a = moment(["2021", "02", "20"]);
var b = moment(["2020", "02", "19"]);

var years = a.diff(b, "year");
b.add(years, "years");

var weeks = a.diff(b, "week");
b.add(weeks, "weeks");

var days = a.diff(b, "days");

console.log(years + " years " + weeks + " weeks " + days + " days");
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bas-fg1c2